# Need to resolve this MySQL error: You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table called tbl_test in a MySQL database:

```
+------+----------+
| user |   dob    |  
+------+----------+
| john | 1/10/96  | 
| jane | 3/4/97   | 
| jill | 1/8/96   | 
| jack | 2/9/00   |
| jane | 12/14/07 | 
| john | 1/11/98  | 
+------+----------+
```

In English, here's what I want to accomplish:

delete all users with dob < 1/1/00 but keep a user if there exists another user with the same name whose dob >= 1/1/00.

In this example, the johns and jill would be deleted and the janes and jack would stay.

I've come up with the following sql command to do this:

```
DELETE from tbl_test
WHERE dob < '2000-01-01'
AND name NOT IN (SELECT name from tbl_test WHERE dob >= '2000-01-01')
```

And MySQL throws this error: You can't specify target table 'tbl_test' for update in FROM clause.

How can I modify the above command to make it legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this trick

```
  DELETE from tbl_test
  WHERE dob < '2000-01-01'
  AND name NOT IN ( select T.name 
                        from (SELECT name 
                              from tbl_test WHERE dob >= '2000-01-01') T)
```

mysql don't allow delete the same table you use for search but you can force to create dinamically a temporary table so this can go over this limit

Answer (score 0):

The normal fix to this is to use `left join`:

```
DELETE t
    FROM tbl_test t LEFT JOIN
         tbl_test tt
         ON t.name = tt.name and tt.dob >= '2000-01-01'
    WHERE t.dob < '2000-01-01' AND
          tt.name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE from user
WHERE name IN (Select name from user where dob < 946684800)
AND name not in (Select name from user where dob > 946684800);
```

Change the number to date I was limited in resources at the time.